# I am getting error in equation

Tags: equations

```
\begin{equation}
prob=\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}\frac{{| s_{i}|}^\alpha{\[ \eta_{i}\]}^\b}{\sum {|s_{i}|}^\alpha{\[ \eta_{i}\]}^\b} \text{$ j\epsilon$ ~route} \\ 0 \mbox{otherwise}
\right\}.
\end{array}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable document that shows the problem. When I copy and compile this I get 21 errors, some, probably are due to not having the correct packages. Please be more specific about what error it is that you are having and post a full [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`

Comment: Bad math environment delimiter

Comment: Don't use `|` for abs value, it gives the wrong spacing in some cases, use `\lvert... \rvert` or even better define a `\abs` macro, see the manual for the mathtools package.

Comment: Use `[...] ` not `\[... \] ` inside your formula. `\[... \] ` has a special meaning

Comment: Additionally, the `\right\}. ` does not make much sense unless moved after `\end{array} `. See also the cases environment

Comment: Thanks,  I have used \lvert...\rvert